# Cannot find the execution point at debug evaluation expression

Tags: appcode

I want log something when breakpoint is hit in AppCode. But there is no documentation for how to write a right evaluation expression for the `evaluate and log`[image] section on debug configuration window.

if i write

```
NSlog(@"some message")//error
```

the console log:

```
error evaluating NSLog(@"some message");: Cannot find the execution point
```

I have no idea how to write correctly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a feature in AppCode called "Evaluate expression" (`⌥F8`). You can call it during the Debug and evaluate particular code expression without `p/po` and LLDB console. You can normally write the code in the window, press "Enter" and see the result of this particular expression.

This field uses this feature to evaluate some particular code at breakpoint, and evaluation result of NSLog is void. Here you can right for example something like `self.view.frame.size.width <= 100` and have result printed to console. If you want just print some message to console - select only **Log message to console** and AppCode will print something like

```
Breakpoint reached: ViewController.m:6
```

Comment: I just want log some customized message, when breakpoint is hit,  it seems unable to do so! `Log message to console` just log standard message! Frustrated!